How does reparametrization of the Fisher information matrix change the variance expression for the sufficient statistics?
If I have an exponential family distribution of the form $$p_{\theta}(x) = e^{\theta^T\cdot t(x) - \psi(\theta)},$$ where $\theta$ is a vector of parameters, $t(x)$ is a vector of sufficient statistics, and $\psi(\theta)$ normalizes such that the pdf integrates to 1, then the Fisher information is the variance of those sufficient statistics. I.e., $$\mathbf{I}_{\theta} = \text{Var}(T(X)).$$
If I am curious about the Fisher information for a nicely behaved function $\tau(\theta)$, I can reparametrize by letting $\mathbf{J}_{ik} = \frac{d\theta_i}{d\tau(
\theta)_k}$ and forming my new Fisher information matrix as $$\mathbf{I}_{\tau(\theta)} = \mathbf{J}^T\mathbf{I}_{\theta}\mathbf{J}.$$
My question is: does this new Fisher information matrix also give an expression for the variance of some function of $X$? Can I write $$\mathbf{I}_{\tau(\theta)} = \text{Var}(U(T(X)))?$$ And if so, how can I find this function $U$ from my function $\tau(\theta)$?
